# PagerTabStrip TalkBack accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I'm currently struggling to create `PagerTabStrip` with more `TalkBack` vocalization.
The context is:

- I want to add "Tab [tab name] not selected, click twice to select" on left and right tabs and "Tab [tab name] selected" to the center one for `TalkBack` user.
- I also want to add a vocalization when a tab is clicked to warn user its content changed and tell `TalkBack` to focus the center tab.

I already succeeded partially doing it by rewriting all the needed classes (for instance: `PagerTitleStrip`, `ViewPager`, `FragmentPagerAdapter`) and adding the right `contentDescription` directly on the tab `TextView`. It works rather well but i'm not satisfied. The maintenance of those classes need to be updated for each new versions of the Android main classes (or i will keep the old design) and i find dirty to copy paste all the class content each time (and what about the next developers ?). 
So, I tried another approches:

- Using `AccessibilityEvent` in a subclass of `PagerTabStrip` to give more context to vocalization. It did not work because `getText()` and `getContentDescription` methods in `AccessibilityEvent` are not used for vocalization.
- Work on `AccessibilityNodeInfo` from `ViewPager` to see if i could work it out. But I have not identify the source of the vocalization (is it tabs or content) nor what must be changed in `AccessiblityNodeInfo` to change vocalization.

So, i wonder whether it is possible or not to use a subclass to solve my problem or if i have no choice but copying the main classes.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple.  What you want to do is create a subclass of PagerTabStrip.  In this subclass, augment the propagation of accessibility events to add the information that you wish!  Below is my implementation.

```
public class A11yPagerTabStrip extends PagerTabStrip {

    public A11yPagerTabStrip(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public A11yPagerTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(View child, AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.wtf(LOG_TAG, "onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent: " + event.toString());

        final String textViewTitle = ((TextView) child).getText().toString();
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) this.getParent();
        final int itemIndex = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

        String title = viewPager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(itemIndex).toString();

        if (textViewTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
            child.setContentDescription("Tab " + textViewTitle + "selected.");
        } else {
            child.setContentDescription("Tab " + textViewTitle + "not selected.");
        }

        return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(child, event);
    }

}
```

Notice that I override the content description. In this way we don't change any of the visual representation of the application, just what talk back reads out.

NOTE: Talkback users are use to the "double tap to select" portion.  I would leave this off, as I have done in my code.

Comment: Thansk a lot, it worked ! I used my OnPageChangeListener to select the current tab with Talkback instead of the last one which has been clicked. I know Android TalkBack users are used to the behavior without indication on what is clickable, i guess i will wait for user tests ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For the tab itself, if you are responsible for inflating the View, then you can use a custom TextView that modifies its content description based on its activated (or selected) state:

```
public class TabTextView extends TextView {

    public TabTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getContentDescription() {
        CharSequence contentDescription = super.getContentDescription();
        return isActivated() ? appendSelectedTo(contentDescription) : contentDescription;
    }

    private String appendSelectedTo(CharSequence contentDescription) {
        return getResources().getString(R.string.tab_selected, contentDescription);
    }
}
```

where `R.string.tab_selected` is `<string name="tab_selected">%1$s selected</string>`

This pre-supposes that you (or [the library you're using](https://github.com/novoda/landing-strip/blob/b9c5322b4afb08f553088bf6f654efb4d1564c26/core/src/main/java/com/novoda/landingstrip/TabsContainer.java#L79)) is marking the tab view with `setActivated(true)/setSelected(true)` when selected (and all the other tabs with `setActivated(false)/setSelected(false)`).

---

The simplest way to announce to the user that the content has changed is to add a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` that announces when the page changes:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO: format correctly with String resource to support translation
        viewPager.announceForAccessibility("Showing " + viewPager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(position));
    }

});
```

---

> I know Android TalkBack users are used to the behavior without indication on what is clickable

There is (by default) an indication on elements that are clickable as @ChrisCM mentioned - TalkBack will append "Double Tap to Activate" (previously "Double Tap to Select") onto Views with a `View.OnClickListener` attached.

You can modify the action that TalkBack reads aloud with an accessibility delegate by overriding the `onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info)` method:

```
class TabAccessibilityDelegate extends AccessibilityDelegateCompat {

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
        info.addAction(
                new AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat(
                        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_CLICK,
                        "select tab"
                )
        );
    }

}
```

and setting it on each of your tab Views:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(tabView, new TabAccessibilityDelegate());
```

such that now TalkBack will read: `"<tab content description>... double tap to select tab"`.

Other ways to customise the usage hint is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41496367/494879).

Comment: It doesn't read my content. It says: "Selected tabtitle1 tab 1 of 4".