# How can I modify the TalkBack usage hint for a clickable View on Android?

Tags: android, talkback

By default, clickable Views on Android will be rendered with a usage hint that's read aloud (if TalkBack is enabled and the user focuses on that View) after the content description:

> "Double tap to activate"

Can I change this so it reads out something less abstract and more specific to my app? Like:

> "Double tap to play video"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible!

### Overriding the `onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo` method

If you have a custom View, you can override the `onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info)` method and add an action with the `ACTION_CLICK` ID, to override the label:

```
@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
    info.addAction(
            new AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction(
                    AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK,
                    "play video"
            )
    );
}
```

If that View has a click listener, then by adding this new `Action`, you'll have overridden the default label so TalkBack will say "Double tap to " instead.

This is only available on API 21 - what if you wanted something that worked on a lower API version or wanted to set a custom usage hint on a non-custom View? You can use `ViewCompat` and `AccessibilityDelegateCompat`!

### Using an AccessibilityDelegate instead

It's very similar - you can override the equivalent method in a custom AccessibilityDelegate that you extend:

```
public static class PlayVideoAccessibilityDelegate extends AccessibilityDelegateCompat {

    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
        info.addAction(
                new AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat(
                        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_CLICK,
                        "play video"
                )
        );
    }
}
```

then to use it, you set the delegate with `ViewCompat`:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(playButton, new PlayVideoAccessibilityDelegate());
```

### Using accessibilitools

Novoda has a utility library to help with accessibility on Android. This includes some tools to help set usage hints:

```
UsageHintsAccessibilityDelegate delegate = new UsageHintsAccessibilityDelegate(resources);  
delegate.setClickLabel("play video");

ViewCompat.setAccesibilityDelegate(playButton, delegate);
```

I wrote a [blogpost which is an overview of accessibilitools](https://www.novoda.com/blog/accessibilitools/) (I am also a contributor to the library).

Comment: I have a custom bottom navigation: https://mdapp.medium.com/accessible-bottom-tab-navigation-on-android-de4396b3f7bd; For me, it says: `Selected tab1. <my custom content>. Tab tab1 1 of 4`. How to remove `Tab tab1 1 of 4` from the end of the sentence?